# Webブラウザのタスクマネージャに表示されるメモリ使用量が想定した数倍のサイズになる

Tags: ios, safari, browser, memory, webgl

UnityのWebGLビルドでアプリケーションを開発しているのですが、Webアプリケーションのヒープサイズや画像ファイル等の合計サイズと比べてブラウザのタスクマネージャに表示されるメモリ使用量が大きく数倍程の開きが出てしまいます。

例えば添付する画像の例ですがアプリケーションで利用しているメモリ使用量は100MB未満ですが、タスクマネージャーで見ると340MB程(Windowsのタスクマネージャのコミットサイズと同じ値)になってしまっています。

PCブラウザであれば4GBまで確保できるためブラウザのメモリに余裕があり、問題にならないのですが、iOSのSafariだと1タブあたり約500MB付近でヒープの割り当てに失敗するようになるのでこの原因を特定したいと考えています。

影響を与えている要素をご存じであればご教示いただけますでしょうか。

[image: MemoryProfiler]

[image: タスクマネージャー]

Comment: 貴方の見ている「メモリ使用量」の定義を検証してください。 Windows のタスクマネージャのメモリ使用量は「アクティブなプライベートワーキングセットサイズ」です（たぶん他の OS のメモリ使用量より小さく見えます）

Comment: "貴方の見ている「メモリ使用量」の定義を検証してください。"とはどういう意味でしょうか？
ブラウザのタスクマネージャーから定義の検証というような操作ができるということでしょうか？

"「Windows のタスクマネージャのメモリ使用量は「アクティブなプライベートワーキングセットサイズ」です（たぶん他の OS のメモリ使用量より小さく見えます"
OSのメモリ使用量との差分ではなくMemoryProfilerに表示されるメモリ量との差分を知りたいのですが、これは何か関係があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 仮想記憶を採用している OS にとってメモリ使用量というのは何種類も定義できるので、そのどれであるかを確認 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33304/ MemoryProfiler が表示しているメモリ量がコミットサイズ相当なら、差が数倍出るのはごく当たり前の話っス。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認したところブラウザのメモリプロファイラに表示されている値はWindowsのコミットサイズと同じ値でした。今回知りたい差分についてはコミットサイズ(ブラウザのプロファイラ表示)とMemoryProfilerとの差分となりますので別の要因かと思います。